# need to display fa-blogger icon

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

I want to add fa-blogger icon same as fa-github icon. But fa-blogger not working for me .

```html
<link href='https://shefaleechaudhary.github.io/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<i class="fa fa-github"></i>
<i class="fa fa-blogger"></i>
<i class="fa fa-blog"></i>
```

I have referred [this](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/455) . Any help on this will be fantastic.

Comment: it is not found in your css

Comment: @SankarRaj Thank you. so, is there any new link of font-awesome css for same ?

Comment: I think font-awesome don't have blogger icon so far. You can try some other things like pngs, svg...

Comment: @user100693 fa-blogger icon is not available at fontawesome till now and it is one of the most popular requests.